# The "FilterByItems" task failed unexpectedly. Azure WebApp Publish

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, io, publish

I am Publishing Web App to Azure using Publish profile and I am getting following Error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(935,5): Error MSB4018: The "FilterByItems" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
at System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(String path)
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.FilterByItems.Execute()
at      Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my project got resolved by removing the highlighted part in the below screenshot:
Replace this in your CustomProfile.pubxml file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

with this:

```
<Project>
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me as well. I suspect the move to Visual Studio 2019 caused it.

Answer (score 0):

My team member has updated '.publishproj' file manually and added some file paths in 'ExcludeFilesFromDeployment' section, which does not exist in my copy of code branch. Removing that paths help to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have been solving this by changing the path to another shorter one.

I created another folder to manage the publishing project to C:/projectfolder/project and when i tried to publish again, it worked

Comment: i did use FolderSystem, i dont know if it can works for WebApp